# DRUPAL: Views, exposed filter: how to unselect all items as default

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Views with an exposed filter with tags. (integrated with Better exposed filter). 
In the settings I can select one or more tags as starting selected tags when I visit the page for the first time.

However I cannot unselect all of them. I would like to not have selected tags at the beginning and at the same to see all articles. (N.B. I'm using "Is one of" operator, and it works perfectly for my website).

So the question is, can I have none tags unselect as default and see all my nodes ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mark the filter as optional.

Comment: thanks for reply, it is actually strange.. if I select / unselect the "Optional" checkbox nothing changes.. I don't see any button to appear, and the tags behavior is the same

Comment: Try removing the filter and re-adding it but making it optional from the beginning. Save.  Go to your view, is there a default selected?